# Sqlite database in ASP environment

Tags: sqlite, asp-classic

Does perform well an ASP website with a SQLite database?

Comment: This question is way too vague to be answerable.  Database performance is entirely up to how you design and use the database.

Comment: depends on the website, depends on the database.

Answer (score 1):

> SQLite usually will work great as the
>   database engine for low to medium
>   traffic websites (which is to say,
>   99.9% of all websites). The amount of web traffic that SQLite can handle
>   depends, of course, on how heavily the
>   website uses its database. Generally
>   speaking, any site that gets fewer
>   than 100K hits/day should work fine
>   with SQLite. The 100K hits/day figure
>   is a conservative estimate, not a hard
>   upper bound. SQLite has been
>   demonstrated to work with 10 times
>   that amount of traffic.

See: http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

In particular, check out the sections labelled: *Situations Where SQLite Works Well*, and *Situations Where Another RDBMS May Work Better*